# Groovy bug: category does now work with abstract iterable classes

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, dsl, metaclass

I've noticed that Groovy version 2.4.x completely breaks my DSL language. After some time, I have reduced the problem: Groovy category now does not work with *abstract iterable* classes.

Consider example:

```
// a very simple Java abstract class that implements Iterable
public abstract class MyAbstractClass implements Iterable<Number> {
    public final int num;

    public MyAbstractClass(int num) { this.num = num; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.valueOf(num); }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Number> iterator() {
        //just some dummy empty iterator
        return new Iterator<Number>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() { return false; }
            @Override
            public Number next() { return null; }
        };
    }
}

// a single implementation
public class MyAbstractClassImpl extends MyAbstractClass {
    public MyAbstractClassImpl(int a) { super(a); }
}

//category that overloads PLUS operator
class MyCategory {
    public static MyAbstractClass plus(MyAbstractClass a, MyAbstractClass b) {
        return new MyAbstractClassImpl(a.num + b.num);
    }
}
```

And the test case:

```
use(MyCategory) {
    def a = new MyAbstractClassImpl(1)
    def b = new MyAbstractClassImpl(2)
    println a + b //expected 3, but received []
    assert (a + b).num == 3 // so here we see exception
}
```

So, instead of using `plus` defined in `MyCategory`, Groovy converts each argument to `List` and then uses `plus` from the default Groovy methods defined for the `List`.

I've created a ticket in Groovy [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7869) tracker, but for now this bug completely breaks my DSL language and I can't force the users to use the previous version of Groovy (in 2.2.x all works fine). So, can one suggest any workaround until this bug will be fixed ? (and if it will be ever fixed...)

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the List.plus() method and then do what you want? (I spent an hour trying this approach, but didn't get anywhere.)

Comment: @MichaelEaster Unfortunately, I also don't known how to intercept List.plus()